# Wierd DockWidgets effect

Tags: qt, qt4, qmainwindow, qdockwidget

Using the `QMainWindow` I have added 3 DockWidgets and set centralWidget to 0, so now  the DockAreas can take  up all the space.

Have a look:

[image]

This looks the way I  want and behaves even more so. But There is one effect that breaks it all.

When I rip `Dock`out of its DockArea, the other DockArea expands and takes up all the space and the Area where `Dock` once resided is gone. I now have something like this:

[image]

From now on it is not possible to dock any widgets right or left, since only one DockArea exists. But can this be fixed? Can I somehow keep a DockArea "alive", even after its only widget was floated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [dockNestingEnabled](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#dockNestingEnabled-prop) property of the QMainWindow to true in order to allow the docks to be docked vertically or horizontally.  Otherwise, you can only do one or the other.